# rkhunter warnings

Tags: rkhunter

Ran rkhunter (centos, cpanel box)

```
    /usr/bin/groups                                          [ Warning ]
    /usr/bin/whatis                                          [ Warning ]
    /usr/bin/ldd                                             [ Warning ]
    /sbin/ifdown                                             [ Warning ]
    /sbin/ifup                                               [ Warning ]

Checking the local host...  
    Checking for hidden files and directories                [ Warning ]


Checking application versions...

    Checking version of Exim MTA                             [ Warning ]
    Checking version of OpenSSL                              [ Warning ]
    Checking version of PHP                                  [ Warning ]
    Checking version of OpenSSH                              [ Warning ]

System checks summary
=====================

File properties checks...
    Required commands check failed
    Files checked: 135
    Suspect files: 5

Rootkit checks...
    Rootkits checked : 249
    Possible rootkits: 0

Applications checks...
    Applications checked: 7
    Suspect applications: 4
```

What should I do from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See log file "/var/log/rkhunter.log" and try to solve Warning(upgrade OpenSSH,OpenSSL,PHP). Be careful not to touch anything, if you do not know what it is